# Why can you loop through an implicit tuple in a for loop, but not a comprehension in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, for-loop, list-comprehension

Is there a reason why looping through an implicit tuple in a `for` loop is okay, but when you do it in a comprehension you get a syntax error?

For example:

```
for i in 'a','b','c': 
    print(i)

'a'
'b'
'c'
```

But in a comprehension:

```
>>> [i for i in 'a','b','c']
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    [i for i in 'a','b','c']
                   ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Is there a reason for this? I wasn't sure about the correct terminology, so my searches yielded nothing useful.

**Update:**

Per the comments, this syntax *is* valid for Python 2.x, but not for Python 3.x.

Comment: i never liked *implicit tuples* so both look bad to me but the question is interesting

Comment: Would it be the `:` that helps to recognize the end of the implicit tuple?

Comment: It works in Python 2.7 but not in Python 3

Comment: Works in 2.7. Not in 3.5.

Comment: Perhaps related to this PEP https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3113/

Comment: Ambiguity? `[i for i in "abc"]` equals ['a','b','c'] so what does one mean by `[i for i in "abc","def"]`?

Comment: @nigel222: That wouldn't be ambiguous, since interpreting it as iterating `"abc"`, then an unrelated comma joined clause of `"def"` would be illegal syntax anyway; a list comprehension can't also define discrete items in the list.

Comment: I was thinking it might  legitimately mean `[['a','b','c'], "def"]` but that the programmer would probably mean `["abc","def"]` ... anyway it's invalid, for which I give thanks to whoever made it so.

Comment: @Scott: That PEP is specific to function calling rules; nothing would prevent the list comprehension from being invoked by packing a tuple before beginning the comprehension. Py3 list comps are implemented as nested scopes invoked in a function-like way, but they don't have parameter lists that are defined in code, they aren't unpacking their arguments in the way that PEP forbids, so that PEP doesn't apply.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

This changed in Python3, mainly in order to make list comprehensions more consistent with generator expressions.

With for-loops and list comprehensions, there is no ambiguity when using a tuple with no parentheses, because the former is always terminated by a colon, and the latter by either a closing bracket or a `for/if` keyword.

However, part of the design of generator expressions requires that they can be used "bare" as function arguments:

```
>>> list(i for i in range(3))
[0, 1, 2]
```

which creates some ambiguity for unparenthesized tuples, because any commas may introduce a new argument:

```
>>> list(i for i in 0, 1, 2)
  File "<stdin>", line 1
SyntaxError: Generator expression must be parenthesized if not sole argument
```

So tuples must always be parenthesized in generator expressions, and the same restriction now also applies to list comprehensions in order to preserve consistency.

PS:

Guido van Rossum wrote a article that spells out all the details on this subject in his History of Python blog:

- [From List Comprehensions to Generator Expressions](https://python-history.blogspot.co.uk/2010/06/from-list-comprehensions-to-generator.html)

Answer (score 3):

Because the `for i in` in the first code is a different syntactical construction than the `for i in` in the second code.

The first case is [a `for` statement, which has the grammar](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-for-statement):

```
for_stmt ::=  "for" target_list "in" expression_list ":" suite
             ["else" ":" suite]
```

`'a', 'b', 'c'` is most definitely an [`expression_list`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#grammar-token-expression_list), so that works out.

In the second case, however, the inline `for` inside square brackets forces the code to be interpreted as a list comprehension, and in Python 3, [list comprehensions must have the syntax](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#displays-for-lists-sets-and-dictionaries):

```
comprehension ::=  expression comp_for
comp_for      ::=  "for" target_list "in" or_test [comp_iter]
comp_iter     ::=  comp_for | comp_if
comp_if       ::=  "if" expression_nocond [comp_iter]
```

Note that the part after the `in` must be an `or_test`, yet comma-delimited expressions create [expression lists](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#expression-lists), and an expression list cannot be an `or_test` --- or, put another way, `or` has higher precedence than comma.  Python thus thinks the comprehension ends at the comma, so that the three elements of the list are:

```
i for i in 'a'
'b'
'c'
```

which (unless you put the `i for i in 'a'` in parentheses) is obviously invalid.

As to why this works in Python 2 ... I'm still looking.

Comment: Is it *obviously* invalid? Python allows lists of arbitrary objects like `[[1,2], "cat", Date]`. Potentially confusing, for sure.

Comment: Per [@ekhumoro's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41128011/364696), it likely worked in Python 2 because list comprehensions were invented in Python 2 before generalized comprehension syntax and generator expressions existed. They didn't behave like generator expressions, set/dict comprehensions, etc., leaking variables into surrounding scope, allowing unparenthesized iterables, etc. In Python 3, for simplification and consistency, list comprehensions were changed to something more closely akin to wrapping a genexpr in the list constructor, and genexpr limits were inherited by side-effect.

Comment: As for the "why this works in Python 2": The grammar explicitly allows for comma-separated lists: [`old_expression`](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#grammar-token-old_expression`).

Comment: Basically, genexpr has a good reason to forbid unparenthesized tuples (as noted in the answer, it creates problems when you're reusing function call parens to wrap the genexpr as a single argument to a function), and listcomps follow the same rules so there aren't subtle gotcha in switching from one to the other.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is here: in the latter case it is not so obvious which objects are you iterating:

```
>>> [i for i in ('a','b','c')]
['a', 'b', 'c']
```

Where's a border between elements? Is it an array of 3 elements: generator and 2 integers?  Like this:

```
>>> [(i for i in 'a'),'b','c']
[<generator object <genexpr> at 0x10cefeeb8>, 'b', 'c']
```

`for` doesn't have such ambiguity - so it doesn't need parenthesis.